# Fatal error : Cannot use [] for reading using smarty template

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, smarty, fatal-error

I am building a ticket support application, and the problem I am having since this weekend, is that when I head to the information page, I land onto the following error:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/miXEZ.png

I looked this error up, and it seems to have to do with an array notation commonly seen as **$arr = [$key][]**

I have scanned my code at the lines of the error, and I cannot seem to trace why my page no longer shows. Underneath my Smarty template and the backend code running behind it:

**Smarty Template: CallScreen.tpl**

https://hastebin.com/pagubejesa.bash

**CallScreen.php running on the background:**

https://hastebin.com/ivezukahut.xml

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, not just dumped on external sites or as a screenshot. Please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I know, but they are quite large files, so I didin't wanted to clutter the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

Error was that the local cache file was not updated, resulting in the error.